# Interface com o mesmo nome de uma classe

Tags: php, classes, interface

```
namespace path;

interface test{
    public function method();
}

class test{

}

class foo implements test{

}
```

Ao escrever o código acima é retornado um erro fatal:

```
Cannot declare class path\test, because the name is already in use in ...  on line 7
```

**Por que não é possível definir uma interface com o mesmo nome de uma classe?**
Isso é um bug ou uma interface é definida como uma classe?
Utilizo o PHP 7.0.1
Encontrei esse link que pode ser um bug, mas ainda não tive como concluir isso:
[Bug #51225     cannot define a class with the same name as an interface](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51225)

Answer (score 4):

> Uma interface é uma declaração de um tipo, e uma classe também é uma declaração de um tipo. **Tipos devem ter nomes distintos no contexto/escopo**.

De outro modo, durante o consumo do tipo, o compilador/interpretador e também quem estivesse lendo o código não saberia a qual tipo você está se referindo.

Veja o seu código exemplo - se você pudesse declarar tanto uma interface quanto uma classe com o nome *Test*, a qual destes dois tipos o código abaixo estaria se referindo?

```
function funcao(Test $test) {
    // ...
}
```

Uma classe pode ter hierarquia e métodos não previstos na interface que ela implementa. O corpo da função acima poderia invocar no parâmetro *$test* os métodos da classe *Test* que não foram declarados na interface *Test*?

Além disso, conceitualmente falando, uma classe e uma interface possuem propósitos distintos, e se o nome de algo deve revelar ou dar uma boa indicação do seu propósito, é natural que coisas com propósitos distintos recebam nomes distintos.

Comment: O tipo vem antes do nome ao definir `interface` e ao usar `implements`. Isso deveria ser possível.

Comment: @RowAraujo Na hora de declarar, sim, você diz se é uma "class" ou uma "interface", e isso serviria para diferenciar. Na hora de utilizar/consumir você não informa se é "class" ou "interface", então não haveria nada mais pra diferenciar além do nome utilizado na declaração.

Comment: Ao usar, o compilador sabe diferenciar a partir da palavra `implements` pq só é possível implementar interfaces! E isso deve ser um bug sim... olha esse link: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51225

Comment: @RowAraujo Acho que o ticket de bug que você linkou está mais relacionado com uma situação da função *class_exists* - ela deveria ou não identificar a interface? Não quero entrar neste mérito do PHP (eu sequer programo em PHP). Fiz um adendo sobre por que, conceitualmente, estas coisas deveriam mesmo ter nomes distintos. E, mais uma vez, o problema de não saber de qual tipo se está falando se daria no **consumo** e não na declaração - a palavra *implements* é usada na declaração da classe e não no consumo.

Comment: Vou pesquisar mais e dps eu dps decido se fecho essa pergunta ou n.

Answer (score 2):

Em OOP, uma interface é uma class com uma flag específica que o identifica como sendo do tipo interface.

O PHP interpreta dessa forma, como se uma interface fosse uma classe. Por isso o erro.

Uma interface deve ter nome que não coincida com o nome de uma classe existente.

Comment: E também, não faz sentido uma classe com mesmo nome de uma interface, são para usos diferentes.